# Search HTML Table with Rows in groups

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css

I have a table shown below, but whenever I search for a cell, the 
left most column disappears because I used one  and spanned it over multiple columns to give the merged field look.

Is there a way to dynamically show a cell that is spanning over multiple cells dynamically so it shows after searching?

Thanks for any help!

```js
function myFunction() {

  // Declare variables 
  var input = document.getElementById("myInput");
  var filter = input.value.toUpperCase();
  var table = document.getElementById("myTable");
  var trs = table.tBodies[0].getElementsByTagName("tr");

  // Loop through first tbody's rows
  for (var i = 0; i < trs.length; i++) {

    // define the row's cells
    var tds = trs[i].getElementsByTagName("td");

    // hide the row
    trs[i].style.display = "none";

    // loop through row cells
    for (var i2 = 0; i2 < tds.length; i2++) {

      // if there's a match
      if (tds[i2].innerHTML.toUpperCase().indexOf(filter) > -1) {

        // show the row
        trs[i].style.display = "";

        // skip to the next row
        continue;

      }
    }
  }

}
```

```css
<style type="text/css">* {
  box-sizing: border-box;
}
#myInput {
  background-image: url('/css/searchicon.png');
  background-position: 10px 10px;
  background-repeat: no-repeat;
  width: 100%;
  font-size: 16px;
  padding: 12px 20px 12px 40px;
  border: 1px solid #ddd;
  margin-bottom: 12px;
}
#myTable {
  border-collapse: collapse;
  width: 100%;
  border: 1px solid #ddd;
  font-size: 18px;
}
#myTable th, #myTable td {
  text-align: left;
  padding: 12px;
border: 1px solid #ddd;
}
#myTable tr {
  border-bottom: 1px solid #ddd;
}
#myTable tr.header, #myTable tr:hover {
  background-color: #f1f1f1;
}
</style>
```

```html
<h3><input id="myInput" onkeyup="myFunction()" placeholder="Search for data.." title="Type in a name" type="text" /></h3>

<table id="myTable">
 <thead>
  <tr class="header">
   <th>
   <h5>Subject</h5>
   </th>
   <th>
   <h5>Teacher</h5>
   </th>
   <th>
   <h5>Building</h5>
   </th>
  </tr>
 </thead>
 <tbody>
  <tr><!--Student Data-->
   <td rowspan="3">
            Math 101
            </td>
   <td>
   <p>Smith</p>
   </td>
   <td>
   Ad 101
   </td>
  </tr>
  <tr>
   
   <td>
   <p>Wang</p>
   </td>
   <td>
   Ad 105
   </td>
  </tr>
  <tr>

   <td>
   <p>Hawk</p>
   </td>
   <td>
   M606
   </td>
  </tr>

  <tr><!--Facilities Engineering and Planning -->
   <td rowspan="3">
   <p>ENG 105 </p>
   </td>
   <td>
   <p>Smith</p>
   </td>
   <td>
   Cambdirge 
   </td>
  </tr>
  <tr>
   
   <td>
   Wong
   </td>
   <td>
   Cambdirge
   </td>
  </tr>
  <tr>
   
   <td>
   Perez
   </td>
   <td>105 </td>
  </tr>
        
 </tbody>
</table>
```

Comment: You can try saving the rowSpan for that particular cell, and when you loop through the tr's, keep the counter if the row is still spanned and then show that particular cell afterwards

Comment: Have you considered DataTables? Also instead of setting display for the `tr` maybe consider just hiding the few `td` instead.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It is possible if you are flexible with `rowSpan` after search..

See the Snippet below:

```js
function myFunction() {

  // Declare variables 
  var input = document.getElementById("myInput");
  var filter = input.value.trim().toUpperCase();
  var table = document.getElementById("myTable");
  var trs = table.tBodies[0].getElementsByTagName("tr");
  var ths = table.tHead.getElementsByTagName("th");
  
  var rowSpan = 1;
  var rowSpanData = '';
  
  // Loop through first tbody's rows
  for (var i = 0; i < trs.length; i++) {

    // define the row's cells
    var tds = trs[i].getElementsByTagName("td");

    // hide the row
    trs[i].style.display = "none";

    // loop through row cells
    for (var i2 = 0; i2 < tds.length; i2++) {

      if(filter!=""){
        if(i2==0 && tds.length == ths.length){
          rowSpanData = tds[i2].innerHTML;
        }
        // if there's a match
        if (tds[i2].innerHTML.toUpperCase().indexOf(filter) > -1) {

          // show the row
          trs[i].style.display = "";

          if(tds.length == ths.length && tds[0].hasAttribute("rowspan") &&  tds[0].getAttribute("rowspan") != 1){
            tds[0].setAttribute("originalRowSpan", tds[0].getAttribute("rowspan"));
            tds[0].setAttribute("rowspan", 1);
          }
          if(tds.length < ths.length){
            var newTd = trs[i].insertCell(0);
            newTd.classList.add("removeMe");
            newTd.innerHTML= rowSpanData;
          }
          // skip to the next row
          continue;

        }
        
      }else{
          trs[i].style.display = "";
          if(tds[i2].hasAttribute("rowspan")){
            tds[i2].setAttribute("rowspan", tds[i2].getAttribute("originalRowSpan"));
          }else if(tds[i2].classList.contains("removeMe")){
            trs[i].deleteCell(0);
          }
      }
    }
  }

}
```

```css
<style type="text/css">* {
  box-sizing: border-box;
}
#myInput {
  background-image: url('/css/searchicon.png');
  background-position: 10px 10px;
  background-repeat: no-repeat;
  width: 100%;
  font-size: 16px;
  padding: 12px 20px 12px 40px;
  border: 1px solid #ddd;
  margin-bottom: 12px;
}
#myTable {
  border-collapse: collapse;
  width: 100%;
  border: 1px solid #ddd;
  font-size: 18px;
}
#myTable th, #myTable td {
  text-align: left;
  padding: 12px;
border: 1px solid #ddd;
}
#myTable tr {
  border-bottom: 1px solid #ddd;
}
#myTable tr.header, #myTable tr:hover {
  background-color: #f1f1f1;
}
</style>
```

```html
<h3><input id="myInput" onkeyup="myFunction()" placeholder="Search for data.." title="Type in a name" type="text" /></h3>

<table id="myTable">
 <thead>
  <tr class="header">
   <th>
   <h5>Subject</h5>
   </th>
   <th>
   <h5>Teacher</h5>
   </th>
   <th>
   <h5>Building</h5>
   </th>
  </tr>
 </thead>
 <tbody>
  <tr><!--Student Data-->
   <td rowspan="3">
            Math 101
            </td>
   <td>
   <p>Smith</p>
   </td>
   <td>
   Ad 101
   </td>
  </tr>
  <tr>
   
   <td>
   <p>Wang</p>
   </td>
   <td>
   Ad 105
   </td>
  </tr>
  <tr>

   <td>
   <p>Hawk</p>
   </td>
   <td>
   M606
   </td>
  </tr>

  <tr><!--Facilities Engineering and Planning -->
   <td rowspan="3">
   <p>ENG 105 </p>
   </td>
   <td>
   <p>Smith</p>
   </td>
   <td>
   Cambdirge 
   </td>
  </tr>
  <tr>
   
   <td>
   Wong
   </td>
   <td>
   Cambdirge
   </td>
  </tr>
  <tr>
   
   <td>
   Perez
   </td>
   <td>105 </td>
  </tr>
        
 </tbody>
</table>
```

Answer (score 1):

Due to the complex nature of your table, you can manipulate the rows with classes for the cells. The helpful element here is the modulus operator ( `%` ). Consider the following jQuery example:

```js
$(function() {
  function up(s) {
    return s.toUpperCase();
  }

  function getData(tObj) {
    var rows = $("tbody > tr", tObj);
    //console.log("GETDATA", rows);
    var r = [];
    var s, c;
    rows.each(function(i, el) {
      var c = $("td", el).not("[rowspan]");
      if (i % 3 == 0) {
        s = $("td[rowspan]", el).text().trim();
      }
      r.push({
        index: i,
        subject: s,
        teacher: c.eq(0).text().trim(),
        building: c.eq(1).text().trim()
      });
    });
    //console.log("GETDATA", r);
    return r;
  }

  function filterTable(q, tbl) {
    var tData = getData(tbl);
    if (q == "") {
      $(".filter", tbl).removeClass("filter");
      return;
    }
    var n = q.toUpperCase();
    $("tbody td", tbl).addClass("filter");
    $.each(tData, function(k, r) {
      var t = up(r.teacher);
      //console.log("CHECK", t, n);
      if (t.indexOf(n) > -1) {
        //console.log("HIT", r);
        $("tbody > tr:eq(" + r.index + ") > td", tbl).removeClass("filter");
        if (r.index % 3 != 0) {
          var m = r.index % 3;
          $("tbody > tr:eq(" + (r.index - m) + ") > td:eq(0)", tbl).removeClass("filter");
        }
      }
    });
  }

  $("#myInput").keyup(function() {
    //console.log("KEY", $(this).val());
    filterTable($(this).val(), $("#myTable"));
  });
});
```

```css
* {
  box-sizing: border-box;
}

#myInput {
  background-image: url('/css/searchicon.png');
  background-position: 10px 10px;
  background-repeat: no-repeat;
  width: 100%;
  font-size: 16px;
  padding: 12px 20px 12px 40px;
  border: 1px solid #ddd;
  margin-bottom: 12px;
}

#myTable {
  border-collapse: collapse;
  width: 100%;
  border: 1px solid #ddd;
  font-size: 18px;
}

#myTable th,
#myTable td {
  text-align: left;
  padding: 12px;
  border: 1px solid #ddd;
}

#myTable tr {
  border-bottom: 1px solid #ddd;
}

#myTable tr.header,
#myTable tr:hover {
  background-color: #f1f1f1;
}

.filter {
  display: none;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<h3><input id="myInput" placeholder="Search for data.." title="Type in a name" type="text" /></h3>

<table id="myTable">
  <thead>
    <tr class="header">
      <th>
        <h5>Subject</h5>
      </th>
      <th>
        <h5>Teacher</h5>
      </th>
      <th>
        <h5>Building</h5>
      </th>
    </tr>
  </thead>
  <tbody>
    <tr>
      <!--Student Data-->
      <td rowspan="3">
        Math 101
      </td>
      <td>
        <p>Smith</p>
      </td>
      <td>
        Ad 101
      </td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
      <td>
        <p>Wang</p>
      </td>
      <td>
        Ad 105
      </td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
      <td>
        <p>Hawk</p>
      </td>
      <td>
        M606
      </td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
      <!--Facilities Engineering and Planning -->
      <td rowspan="3">
        <p>ENG 105 </p>
      </td>
      <td>
        <p>Smith</p>
      </td>
      <td>
        Cambdirge
      </td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
      <td>
        Wong
      </td>
      <td>
        Cambdirge
      </td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
      <td>
        Perez
      </td>
      <td>105 </td>
    </tr>
  </tbody>
</table>
```

Your examples used Native JS, yet you had it tagged for jQuery so I am offering up this example. Basically, we can create an array of data from the table and then filter it when searching.

You can improve this by finding the `rowspan` attribute and using this instead of just hard coding `3`.

I am filtering by hiding all elements, by adding the class `filter`, and then revealing the matches, by removing the `filter` class, when a search is entered. I also unhide the `rowspan`.

Answer (score 0):

Went through you code, I would recommend either you can make nested table structure and update you java script or just use data table here is the linnk
https://datatables.net/examples/styling/bootstrap4.html

-Thanks